# Accessing a customer parameter from the General Preferences Tab in NetSuite

Tags: pdf, netsuite

I am using a user event script to print a PDF file from a Sales Order.
I have added a couple of parameters to the script to capture a couple of configurable data items I wish to access on the printed PDF.
The configurable parameters are available on the General Preferences tab.  I have filled in some test data values into the fields.
However, I do not know how to access the data items in the PDF code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the User or Company general preferences tab? How are you generating the PDF? If via a script what sort of script and if it's not a User Event script or Client script how is it triggered? If via a script can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have been able to resolve this.

Comment: I have been able to resolve this.  It is a user event script that puts the values on the Company general preferences tab. The issue was with my printing script.  Thank you for the response.